# How can I use puppeteer for cachewarmer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a long `txt` file with ~1000 urls, which needs to be executed, to warm the varnish cache.
Since I need puppeteer, is that there is important content loaded by AJAX call.

This is my first attempt, but not master in node.
The real issue is that it make a 100% load, and starts too many threads.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('varnish-warmer.txt')
  });

rl.on('line', (line) => {
(async () => {
    if (line != '') {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(line);
        await page.waitFor(1000);

        browser.close();
    }

})();
});
```

Comment: This code launches 1000 browser instances in parallel. What Node.js version do you use? And would it be appropriate if you open these pages in series, one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, your code launches all browsers in parallel which overloads your system. You could either visit each URL one after another (option 1) or use a [pool of browsers](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) to speed the process up (option 2).

#### Option 1

Launches one browser and visits all pages one after another:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

const lines = fs.readFileSync('varnish-warmer.txt').toString().split('\n');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    for (const line of lines) {
        await page.goto(line);
        await page.waitFor(1000);
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

#### Option 2

As option 1 might take a while for 1000 URLs, you might want to use a pool of browsers to visit the pages in parallel and speed things up. You can use [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) for that (disclaimer: I'm the author of the library).

```js
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_BROWSER,
        maxConcurrency: 10, // how many URLs should be visited in parallel
        // monitor: true, // uncomment to see information about progress
    });

    // Define the task for each URL
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitFor(1000);
    });

    // Queue the URLs
    const lines = fs.readFileSync('varnish-warmer.txt').toString().split('\n');
    lines.forEach(line => cluster.queue(line));

    // Wait for the tasks to finish and close the cluster after that
    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();
```

You can play around with the value of `maxConcurrency` to change the number of workers depending on the capabilities (CPU/memory) of your system.

Comment: Thank you, im going with option 2, the puppeteer-cluster works like a charm here.